# Get all records for user from database

Tags: php, mysql

In my table 'user_sightings' I allow multiple entries for each user, so it looks as follows...

```
------------------------
ID | user_ID | postcode
1     39       ab12cd
2     39       sk91ab
3     39       ab44ix
```

After running my query I try to print out each postcode with the following...

```
echo $row["postcode"];
```

only this only prints out the first instance for that user, Is their a way I can get all instances for the user and dynamically set them as variables?

---

Query:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory, user_sightings WHERE directory.user_active != '' AND directory.ID = :uid AND user_sightings.user_ID = :uid");
$sth->execute(array(':uid' => $UID));

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $row["postcode"];
 }
```

Comment: What's the actual query?

Comment: Could you add a little more of your code, too?

Comment: That query doesn't touch the `postcodes` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `while` loop to [fetch the rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), then you can use [variable assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP to assign a variable to each user:

```
while($row ... {
    ${$row[user_ID]} = $row[postcode];
}
```

You will need a way to uniquely identify the variables, because then the last instance of that `user_ID` will be the value of that variable I would recommend using an array. Perhaps something like:

```
${'user_' . $row[user_ID]}[] = $row[postcode];
```

This way, `$user_39` will become an array containing `(ab12cd, sk91ab, ab44ix)`.

Or you can throw all your data into an array like so:

```
$user_ID = $row[user_ID];
$array[$user_ID][] = $row[postcode];
```

Either of those two options would go inside your `while` loop.

**Clarification**

If you want to call the postcode for a particular user, first put the data into a multi-dimensional array:

```
while($row ... {
    $user_ID = $row[user_ID];
    $array[$user_ID][] = $row[postcode];
}
```

The postcodes will then be stored like so (following example in question):

```
echo $array[39][0];
//ab12cd

echo $array[39][1];
//sk91ab

echo $array[39][2];
//ab44ix
```

`[39]` represents the `user_ID`

Comment: variable assignment?
use an associative array.  its MUCH clearer that way

Comment: Thanks @njk, will this go within my current loop?

Comment: @Liam either of the two options would go inside your `while` loop.

Comment: How would I split the array and assign each value to a variable @njk?

Comment: @Liam What do you mean by `each value` and what does each value define?

Comment: Well the above ouputs 2 postcodes side by side 'WA74NUSK91AB', is it possible to say $postcode1 = 'wa74nu' and $postcode2 = 'sk91ab';

Comment: @Liam It is difficult to tell what you are referring to. Do you wish to have the `user_ID` as a variable that contains an array of postal codes?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18537/discussion-between-liam-and-njk)

Comment: basically @njk im trying to plot points on a google map, so to do that i need to explode that array into variables? if thats the correct terminology

Comment: @Liam See the clarification in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory, user_sightings WHERE directory.user_active != '' AND directory.ID = :uid AND user_sightings.user_ID = :uid");
$sth->execute(array(':uid' => $UID));
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {  
echo $row['postcode'] . "\n";  
    }
```

Comment: Would I place this within my current loop? Sorry im very new to PDO